# How to fold a disk into a cylinder while the edge are touching

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I am really new to blender and I am looking to do modeling. How I can show a circular disk folds into becoming a hollow cylinder?

Comment: hello, do you have a picture of what you want?

Answer (score 3):

Let's try this:

- Create a cylinder (*Fill Type* > *Ngon*), rotate it so it faces the view, apply the rotation with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>.
- In *Edit* mode, inset with <kbd>i</kbd>.
- Inset again and <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge at Center*.
- Create some edge loops with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> to add some topology.
- Give your object a *Simple Deform* modifier, *Bend* mode, with a 360° *Deform Angle*.
- Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, press the *Smooth Shading* button on the Tools panel.
- To give your object some thickness you can add a *Solidify* modifier, put it above your *Subdivision Surface* modifier, and choose the *Thickness* value that suits you.
- To have a sharp edge make sure to have an edge loop close to the edge.

[image]